# Javascript API for Vector Graphics that implement a Scene Graph

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I'm looking for a JavaScript Framework for creating 2D Graphic's like Raphael or Fabric. I like both APIs but I am missing an object oriented way to create a Scene Graph with a composite pattern.

Does anybody know such a Framework?

To make clear what I mean by composite pattern: I would like to arrange the painted objects in a tree like it is done in GUI Frameworks like swt or swing (Java3D uses this too I think).
There you have a

- *Component* as parent class for all Objects that are painted. It describes common behavior and attributes for all Objects that get painted.
- *Container* that extends from *Component* and contains a list of *Components*. So *Container* behaves like a single *Component* and delegates all operations on *Container* to all its children-Components.

Using this two classes makes it very easy to create a Scene graph...

Is there a 2D Framework out there that uses this pattern?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an idiom (i.e. a language-specific design pattern), so you could implement it in JavaScript as well, but I don't see why you would want that.

Some JS frameworks (or libraries) offer a well opinionated solution and structured workflow - such as [sceneJS](http://scenejs.org/) (though it *is* essentially a *3D* engine) or [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) - that eliminates the need for implementing such patterns.

You haven't elaborated on *how* the composite pattern helps with creating scenegraphs, so I can't help you there, but here are some examples from people how have been there and lived to tell the tale:

- Mike Bostock (author of D3.js) has written [a POC for a canvas scenegraph in the DOM](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1276463) (!), which you may find interesting.
- On the JSter blog there is [a post](http://jster.net/blog/brief-overview-of-html5-canvas-libraries#.UhaWjd8_mXo) suggesting to *“complement [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) with [AtelierJS](https://github.com/bloomingbridges/AtelierJS)”* (AtelierJS actually describes itself as a *“scene management module for CreateJS”*).
- It's also mentioned in that very post that **[Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) implements scenegraph as a core feature**, so it's worth looking at (actually, it might just be *exactly* what you're after).
- Also check out [CakeJS](https://code.google.com/p/cakejs/), which is said to be *“a JavaScript scene graph library for the HTML5 canvas tag”*.

Comment: I don't miss the composite pattern in JavaScript in general, I miss it in 2D Graphic API's. Since I know only a few Graphic APIs I thought there might be some more out there. Thats why I created the thread here :-)

Comment: Why would I want the composite pattern: A scene graph is a tree structure that can be used to organize translation, transformation, scale and rotation of its nodes and leafs. This operations can be called for nodes and for leafs. Both are expected to act in the same way, but operations on nodes are delegated to all its children. One classical way to create that is the composite pattern - if you are in the object oriented world. I like it for its natural clarity - thats why I want that :-) But I'm always curious to learn more, or even better ways :-)

Comment: Paper.js is indeed very close to what I am looking for, I'm just not shure about this PaperScript-JavaScript overlay. I want to use Coffee-Script and I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: CakeJS is said not to be maintained anymore... don't know if this is really true, but the last changes on https://code.google.com/p/cakejs/ are indeed a little old

Comment: The other stuff is new to me, thank you for your Ideas!!!